# Doing PHP through dropbox, and new to programming. How do I set up?

Tags: php

I bought space from dropbox for personal use, and I found out they have a public folder where I can share my files like a website.  I wanted to learn PHP save saving my files into my dropbox folder, and this will not require me any FTP.

I don't know much about website programming.  I have some background in technical programming for work.  But that's it.  I tried to follow [this page](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/php), but I really don't understand them.  I have also viewed [this youtube page](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FsQZyNpDWv0), but it's not window based, and I got stuck on using composer.  I followed as best as I could, but all the samples in the SDK never shows up correctly. Anyone with any other sources to help me get started on setting up PHP through my dropbox?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is what I always get when I view the [examples](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/119948822/Project/examples/web-file-browser.php)

Comment: I am not familiar with the dropbox sdk, but the pages you posted look like instructions for installing the dropbox sdk on a server.  This sdk would run on a web server and would help you access the dropbox api, so that you could do cool dropbox functions from your website.  It doesn't look like those examples are for what you want.  There is an easy test, make a file called test.php, put this in it, `<?php echo "hello world"; ?>` and go to that file in your browser.  Then you'll know.

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/119948822/Project/test.php

Comment: that would be a no.  :(

Comment: Damn.  Alright.  Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: there are probably lots of places to find free lamp hosting.  just not dropbox it seems

Comment: I thought it would be extremely cool if I could upload songs and movies to my dropbox.  I've already paid $99.00 for a year of subscription for 1 tb.  I barely use any of the space.  I thought I could start learning a new programming language with some of the space.  I guess I can do it through HTML

Comment: You might want to host HTML for free on GitHub: https://pages.github.com